# How to add a column in each csv file where the value of the column is dependent on the name of the csv

Tags: r

I have 50 folders. Within each folder I have four datasets with name: xx_14, xx_15, xx_16, xx_17. The number indicates the year. For each folder I need to merge the four datasets together.

I also need to create a new column in the merged dataset (for each folder) where the value under that column is the year (time period) corresponding to the year of these four datasets.

I can't just manually do them in R because I have 50 folders, each with such type of 4 datasets, so I would need to create a for loop for these 50 folders. Whatever folder it is, the csv files always take the form of xx_14 or 15 or 16 or 17.

Comment: Hi Feng, it is important that we see your full code to be able to help you solve this problem, including the format of your four datasets (and potentially subsets of at least two of them, perhaps captured using `dput` so we can reproduce the merge. The best questions on here have enough code to cut and paste into our own R sessions and quickly reproduce your issue locally. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this base R approach :

```
#Get list of all 50 folders
all_folders <- dir("/path/to/outer/folder", full.names = TRUE)

#Loop over each folder
lapply(all_folders, function(x)  {
   #Get all the filenames in that folder
   file_path <- list.files(x, full.names = TRUE)
   #Read all the files and rbind them
   do.call(rbind, lapply(file_path, function(x) 
           #Add a new column with name of the filename
           transform(read.csv(x), year = sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(x)))))
})
```